# Rotate a 3D Object using Touch inputs in iOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, 3d, rotational-matrices

I am working on an ios application where I need to rotate a 3d matrix (3D object) just by swiping a finger over it. the method i use for the rotation is

setRotationMatrix(float angle, float x, float y, float z, float *matrix);

However I am not sure how to use the touch's x and y location values in order to rotate the 3D matrix correctly. Here is the code that I am using

-(IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

```
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        panStartPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self];
        previousPoint.x = 0;
        previousPoint.y = 0;
        currentPoint.x = panStartPoint.x;
        currentPoint.y = panStartPoint.y;
    }
    else if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        panEndPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self];
    }
    else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        previousPoint.x = currentPoint.x;
        previousPoint.y = currentPoint.y;
        CGPoint instanteneousPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self];
        currentPoint.x = instanteneousPoint.x;
        currentPoint.y = instanteneousPoint.y;

        int xdifference = currentPoint.x - previousPoint.x;
        int ydifference = currentPoint.y - previousPoint.y;



        if((xdifference <= rotationThreshold *-1) || xdifference >= rotationThreshold)  //rotationThreshold = 3;
        {
            if(xdifference <= rotationThreshold *-1)
            {
                rotationY = -1.0;
            }
            else
            {
                rotationY = 1.0;
            }

            if( (ydifference >= rotationThreshold *-1) && ydifference <= rotationThreshold )
            {
                rotationX = 0.0;
            }
        }

        if((ydifference <= rotationThreshold *-1) || ydifference >= rotationThreshold)
        {
          if((ydifference <= rotationThreshold *-1))
          {
            rotationX = -1.0;
          }
          else
          {
              rotationX = 1.0;
          }
            if( (xdifference >= rotationThreshold *-1) && xdifference <= rotationThreshold )
            {
                rotationY = 0.0;
            }

        }
        if(rotationX != 0.0 || rotationY != 0.0)
        {
            rotationDegree += 5.0f;
            if(rotationDegree >= 360.0f)
            {
                rotationDegree = 0.0f;
            }
            ShaderUtils::rotatePoseMatrix(rotationDegree, rotationX, rotationY, rotationZ, &modelViewMatrix.data[0]); //rotationZ = 0;
        }}}
```

This is providing me with some rotation of the 3D object but its not as natural as it should be. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well..i never used used UIPanGestureRecognizer so i dont know how and why doesnt it work but i used UITouch to move a 3d object (i find it to be easyer)

ok..so here is what i did (i dont have the code anymore so i cant give it to you ...sorry):

you get the first touch with touchesBegan (`UITouchPhaseBegan`)

then, if touchesMoved you rotate the object over x axis if touch moved on y and rotate it on y axis if touch moved on x ..and any combination of the 2 (you have to set sensitivity yourself)

also you have the option to move the object in view like this: you tap twice and then move the finger (like a laptop's track pad)

to move it on the z axis just use `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`

its obvious you can't move a 3d object in all 3 dimensions with a 2d surface

for more look in [UITouch class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITouch)

i may not have explained very well...but you get the basic idea

Comment: Thanks skytz. Pan gesture is more or less the same as UITOUCH. As described in my code, i am following exactly the same logic that you described.  And it rotates as well, but the rotation doesn't seem so natural. After searching on the net for countless hours, I have got this idea that in order to rotate a 3d object with 2D gesture, you first have to convert that matrix into its original position, then find its quaternion (whatever that is) and multiply them together. or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12667/how-to-rotate-a-3d-object-using-touches-with-opengl) should help you. It is tutorial with several ways to make it in the right way